# Code cleanup and question about use of import os

Tags: python-3.x, mkdir, shutil

I suppose this is more of a critique for my code, but I want to see if there was a more clean alternative way to write out what I did. Also, as a best practice with Python, should I not import os and sys? What would be a good alternative?

As a background, I started a new role and wanted to keep up with my python but automating some boring stuff. I want to keep my notes and files for clients as organized as possible, so what I did was create a script that would take my custom input to create a new directory, then copy the format of my Notes text file to the new directory. The script works fine, but, I feel it looks a bit sloppy.

```
#! python3
# Python script to create directory, and copy text file for notes

import sys
import os
from shutil import copyfile

# define the path to the location and use name for the title of your 
directory
path = "/Users/myname/"
name = path + sys.argv[1]

#create the directory with access rights if you want them to be there
try:
  os.mkdir(name)
except OSError:
  print("Creation of directory %s failed" % name)
else:
  print("Successfully created the directory %s" % name)

copyfile('/Users/myname/Notes', name + '/Notes')
```

When I call the script, my input after the script name is what I intend for the new directory to be called. (below, 'NewName' is what I want my new directory to be called.)

ex. `python3 create.py NewName`

Following that, if the creation was successful, then my Notes file from the home directory would be copied to the newly created directory.

Comment: If you didn't import `sys`, you couldn't access `sys.argv`.  If you didn't import `os`, you couldn't call `os.mkdir()`.  How are you imagining that your program could do what it needs to do without those?

Comment: I had read about security vulnerabilities with importing os and sys when you execute python. I understand the question seems silly, but I want to see if there was indeed another way.

Comment: The things you have to worry about with those modules are along the lines of calling `os.system()` with a command string carelessly built from user input; the user could type a separator and a second arbitrary command, that would be executed along with the one you intended.  Merely having those modules imported would only be a problem if you were executing untrusted Python code - but such code could simply import the modules itself if it wanted to abuse them.